# Не подключаются модули

Tags: python, консоль, модули

Вот пример ошибки

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\????????\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\????????\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install colorama': ?? ??????? ????? ????????? ????.
```

Comment: Опишите, когда возникают проблемы. Что делаете, что устанавливаете, что подключаете, как подключаете.

Comment: В cmd прописываю pip install colorama

Comment: может быть из-за кирилицы в пути